# No able to run pm2 on Windows server 2012

Tags: node.js, npm, pm2

I installed `pm2` on Windows server 2012

```
npm install pm2 -g
```

I closed my PowerShell and opened it again.

When I try to run `pm2` it fails with this error

```
> pm2 list

pm2 : The term 'pm2' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pm2 list
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pm2:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I noticed `PM2_HOME` was not set, so I set it to my `.pm2` in my home directory, but that didn't help

Any pointers?

What is interesting, is that I have it working on another account on the same machine.

Answer (score 22):

Had the same problem on one Windows 2012R2 server PM2 was working and the other one not.
In the Environment there was no path to

`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm`

After adding the path and a restart of the server PM2 was recognized in PowerShell and CMD.

> There is no need to add PM2 path to the System variables.

[image]

Comment: Just linking back github's issue. https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2566

Answer (score 3):

There is Bountysource fundraising to make PM2 compatible with Windows:

- https://www.bountysource.com/teams/keymetricsio/fundraisers/600-pm2-windows-support

which means that currently it is not completely compatible.

See also this issue:

- https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/6

with this comment from Unitech:

> PM2 is a production module, who should be mainly used on Linux servers. I haven't tried it on other platforms than Linux.

Comment: BTW I had it working on another user account on the same machine and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

just install pm2 in global mode

```
npm install pm2 -g -s
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be resolved by adding the path of npm to the env setting. At least that did the trick for me.

Answer (score -2):

Here How to solve it:

1. Select Start > All Programs > Windows PowerShell version > Windows PowerShell.
2. Type only: Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

Try to execute again.